# How to use python with phantomjs and selenium fake referer?

Tags: phantomjs

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 "
)
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get("http://pujiankang.cn/index0.html")
jscode = '''
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var settings = {
  headers: {
   "Referer": "http://www.google.com"
  }
};
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    page.customHeaders = {};
};

page.open('http://pujiankang.cn/index0.html', settings, function(status) {
});
'''

driver.execute_script(jscode)
driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
driver.quit
```

when run it then get error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ83Y.png)

[errorMessage":"Can't find variable: require","request"...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ83Y.png)

But I run this js file with phantomjs directly,It's work!

command:phantomjs referer.js

How to resolve this problem?